# JQGrid pager not showing until I change view

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Here's my code:

```
<table id="employees"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#employees").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        colNames: ['Employee #', 'Name', 'Trade'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'num', index: 'num', width: 100, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 300 },
            { name: 'trade', index: 'trade', width: 80 },
        ],
        multiselect: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "num",
        sortorder: "desc",
        scroll: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        height: 'auto',
        caption: "Equipment"
    });

    var mydata = [
        { num: "492", name: "Doug Anderson", trade: "WS" },
        { num: "696", name: "William Anderson", trade: "OP" },
        { num: "826", name: "Chris Autry", trade: "WF" },
        { num: "206", name: "Tom Beffa", trade: "OP" },
        { num: "799", name: "Glenn Bixler", trade: "LB" },
        { num: "360", name: "Pete Bober", trade: "OP" },
        { num: "7", name: "Scott Burgie", trade: "PFW" },
        { num: "476", name: "James Click", trade: "W" },
        { num: "775", name: "Bryan Darst", trade: "LB" },
        { num: "249", name: "Bob Dunham", trade: "LB" },
        { num: "10", name: "Tom Ekclund", trade: "WGF" },
        { num: "390", name: "Noel Edwards", trade: "W" }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
        jQuery("#employees").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
</script>
```

My issue is that the pager shows, but says "1 out of 0" and then just shows all the rows instead of just 10. What's weird is that if I change the sort column once the page is loaded, or change the number of rows to show, it starts to work properly. For example, if I loaded the page and switched the number of rows to display to 20, it would show "1 out of 1" at the bottom, and then if I set it back to 10, I'd have 2 pages that I could switch through. I just don't get why it's not working immediately after page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the described problem is the usage of `addRowData` to fill the data. It's very bad, that the official jqGrid [demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.htm) contains very close code which can be found under "Loading Data" / "Array Data". The code contains not only small error (`i <= mydata.length` should be replaced to `i < mydata.length`), but it's *very ineffective. The demo page is very old. Starting with jqGrid 3.7 (see "New in version 3.7" / "Load array data at once") there are exist much more effective way: usage of `data` parameter.

Instead of filling the data in loop you can extend every item of `mydata` array with additional property `id` and use just `data: mydata` option. In the case the data will be first sorted (corresponds to `sortname: "num"`, `sortorder: "desc"` which you use) and then the first page will be displayed. The user can use pager to navigate over the pages of data.

If the value of `num` which you displays is already unique (have different values in every row) then you don't need to add `id` property to `mydata` array. Instead of that you can add `key: true` property in the definition of `num` column in `colModel`. After that jqGrid will use the value from `num` column as "rowid" (the value of `id` attribute assigned to `<tr>` elements of the grid).

Additionally I recommend you to use `gridview: true` option in all your grids and remove `index` from `colModel` if you use the same value as `name`. By the way if you use datatype: "local" you **must** either remove `index` or specify the same values for `index` and `name`.

So the final code could be something like below

```
var mydata = [
        { num: "492", name: "Doug Anderson", trade: "WS" },
        { num: "696", name: "William Anderson", trade: "OP" },
        { num: "826", name: "Chris Autry", trade: "WF" },
        { num: "206", name: "Tom Beffa", trade: "OP" },
        { num: "799", name: "Glenn Bixler", trade: "LB" },
        { num: "360", name: "Pete Bober", trade: "OP" },
        { num: "7", name: "Scott Burgie", trade: "PFW" },
        { num: "476", name: "James Click", trade: "W" },
        { num: "775", name: "Bryan Darst", trade: "LB" },
        { num: "249", name: "Bob Dunham", trade: "LB" },
        { num: "10", name: "Tom Ekclund", trade: "WGF" },
        { num: "390", name: "Noel Edwards", trade: "W" }
    ];

$("#employees").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    colNames: ["Employee #", "Name", "Trade"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "num", width: 100, key: true, sorttype: "int" },
        { name: "name", width: 300 },
        { name: "trade", width: 80 },
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "num",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "auto",
    gridview: true,
    caption: "Equipment"
});
```

I fixed small bug: you specified `height` property twice (`height: 250` and `height: 'auto'`) which is an error.

Comment: Thanks so much! Since you seem to know what you're talking about with JQGrid, could you tell me, is it also possible to search locally? Currently, it looks like the only way to search is by passing the query through the "url" attribute and having it return new data, but I'd prefer a way that's just javascript, if that's possible.

Comment: @user1579458: You are welcome! I fixed the code just now with including `key: true` and `gridview: true`. The local searching should work. If you need case insensitive searching you can use `ignoreCase: true` option. To searching itself you can use either standard Searching Dialog added by `navGrid` or use `filterToolbar` for Toolbar Searching. I'll modify your code and will post you the demo.

Comment: @user1579458: For example, try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user1579458.htm). Click on "Search" button and choose "Name" "contains" "am". You will see 3 rows of data.

Comment: Thanks for the demo! It works great there--but for some reason, I can't get it to work with my grid. Search button shows up, but whenever I try to make a query, it just says "Loading" and nothing happens. I tried copying the source code from that page but even then it won't run right. Could you post the code I should use to get it to work?

Comment: @user1579458: you can open source of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user1579458.htm) in any web browser. If you have problem in some demo you should post the URL to the demo or you can place the full code of the demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link to the jsfiddle-demo.

Comment: I copied your source code exactly into an html file and it works fine. However, when putting that exact same code into my MVC view, it stops working. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently MVC has a line at the bottom of the default _Layout.cshtml that renders scripts, and so it tried rendering jquery twice, which, for whatever reason, was the problem. Thanks for all the help!